# Unable to run a script from node_modules/.bin

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber, node-modules

I have the following line in my code - `require.resolve(".bin/cucumber-js")`. However, when I see `cucumber-js` , it actually calls `run.js` like this - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/bin/cucumber-js which eventually needs to be picked from `@cucumber/cucumber` under node modules. However, the dir structure fails this.

```
dir structure - 
|_node_modules
  |_.bin
    |_cucumber-js
  |_ @cucumber/cucumber
    |_bin
      |_cucumber-js
    |_lib
      |_cli
        |_run.js
```

I debugged using the following options -

- `require.resolve("@cucumber/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js")` - This makes us dependent on @cucumber/cucumber - which is another package's dependency and we don't want to add it to ours).Also, it fails with the error - `Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './bin/cucumber-js' is not defined by "exports" in <package-path-on-local>/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/package.json`
- `require.resolve("cucumber-js")` - This again picks it up from `.bin` and fails because it cannot find `run.js`
- I tried updating the command directly `npx cucumber-js <>` , and this works fine in both local and pipeline. However, I see `cucumber-js` is still present in `.bin` . I don't understand that how this is different from above 2. Any idea on this?

I want to understand the following -

- What is the right way of fixing this?
- Why during local executions it gets resolved from `@cucumber/cucumber` inside node-modules , instead of `.bin`.